# Outlook out of memory error for user with large PST files with a VSTO addin

Tags: outlook, add-in

I had a few questions regarding memory in Outlook 2010, Windows 7 64 bit. We have a customer machine, who has Outlook running, with a large number of PST files at about 50 G size. We also have an outlook addin that Outlook loads. We find that on occasion that this addin runs out of memory, doesn’t have any memory to continue with its stuff. Also some of the copy and paste operations in Outlook fail. This problem for the addin doesn’t happen on any of the 100’s of other machines we have the addin running.

Also the number of handles used is over 9,000 (even without any addins), and with addins added it reaches about 11k sometimes. Will this be a problem even in High end Windows 7 64 bit machine?

I have few questions:

Have you guys tested with these large PST files and was everything fine for you?

Is there any way to increase the maximum allocated amount available per addin or for all addins? A registry key perhaps?

Outlook seems to start throwing these errors when it reaches about 300 Meg of memory, even though there is plenty of memory still available. Shouldn’t it grow to 1G if it needs to?

Comment: It sounds like you have a **memory leak**. You need to [research proper COM disposal](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2008/10/30/releasing-office-objects-net/).